# How do I abort a scan but retain the flag element of the sequence: skipToOrDefault

Tags: functional-programming, f#, ocaml

I have a sequence of `Result` and I would like to accumulate all the `Error` values yet abort processing and return the first `Ok` value found. Specifically, I would like to abort processing the remainder of the list. Unfortunately, the approach I have preserves the first `Ok` found but does not abort processing the rest of the list.

```
let process : Result<'t, string list> -> Result<'t, string list> =
    let st0 = Error []
    let acc st e =
       match st, e with 
       | Ok _   , _        -> st
       | _      , Ok _     -> e
       | Error v, Error vs -> Error (v ++ vs)
    Seq.scan acc st0
    |> Seq.last
```

Ideally, a `Seq.skipToOrDefault` and `Seq.takeToOrDefault` methods would be nice to have for this.

Comment: How do you know that this approach doesn't abort processing of the rest?

Comment: It isn't evident in the code that is necessarily the case.

Comment: I do understand what the code does. What isn't clear is what do you mean by "processing". To clarify that, I phrased my question in a testable way. If you answer how you know that it's being "processed", we can use that as a test to verify potential solutions - i.e. a good solution is that in which your test will indicate "not processing".

Comment: Sequence is not side effect free. Consequently, one must expect the entire collection to be processed (iterated through) by default.

Comment: That doesn't sound like something that can be tested. Let me try to read your mind then: do you, by any chance, mean that you would like to avoid _iterating_ over the whole sequence?

Comment: Yes. My apologizes for the difficult. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is a better solution. However, there is some confusion as to whether `Seq.tryPick` is always side effect free regardless of the underlying sequence. For `list` it is such that `Seq.tail` is required here to advance through it...

```
let rec scanTo (pred:'u -> bool) (acc:'u -> 'a -> 'u) (st0:'u) (ss:'a seq) = seq {
    let q = 
        ss 
        |> Seq.tryPick Some 
        |> Option.bind (acc st0 >> Some)

    match q with
    | None               -> yield! Seq.empty
    | Some v when pred v -> yield v
    | Some v             -> yield v; yield! (scanTo pred acc v (Seq.tail ss))
    }
```

For instance...

```
let process : Result<'v, string list> seq -> Result<'v, string list> seq = fun aa ->
    let mergeErrors acc e = 
        match acc, e with
        | Error ms, Error m -> Error (m @ ms)
        | _, Ok v           -> Ok v
        | _, Error m        -> Error m

    let st0 = Error []

    let isOk = function 
        | Ok _ -> true 
        | _    -> false

    scanTo isOk mergeErrors st0 aa
```

Answer (score 3):

From your comments, it has become clear that what you'd like to do is to avoid *iterating* over the whole sequence, stopping once you encounter the first `Ok`.

Well, sequences already do that by default (they're *lazy*), and the `scan` function preserves that property. Let's check:

```
let mySeq = seq {
    for i in 0..3 do
        printfn "Returning %d" i
        yield i
}

mySeq |> Seq.toList |> ignore
> Returning 0
> Returning 1
> Returning 2
> Returning 3

mySeq |> Seq.take 2 |> Seq.toList |> ignore
> Returning 0
> Returning 1

mySeq 
    |> Seq.scan (fun _ x -> printfn "Scanning %d" x) () 
    |> Seq.take 3
    |> Seq.toList |> ignore
> Returning 0
> Scanning 0
> Returning 1
> Scanning 1
```

Look: we never see "Returning 2" and "Returning 3" after the `scan`. That's because we're not iterating over the whole sequence, only the piece we need, as determined by `Seq.take 3`.

But the thing that *does* force the full iteration in your code is `Seq.last`. After all, in order to get the last element, you need to iterate over the whole sequence, there is no other way.

But what you can do is stop iteration when you need via `Seq.takeWhile`. This function takes a predicate and returns only the elements for which the predicate is `true`, excluding the first one that yields `false`:

```
mySeq |> Seq.takeWhile (fun x -> x < 2) |> Seq.toList |> ignore
> Returning 0
> Returning 1
> Returning 2
> val it : int list = [0; 1]
```

The difficulty in your case is that you also need to return the element that breaks the predicate. In order to do that, you can deploy a little hack: keep around in your folding state a special flag `stop: bool`, initially set it to `false`, and switch to `true` on the element immediately succeeding the one where you need to stop. To keep such state, I am going to use a record:

```
let st0 = {| prev = Error []; stop = false |}

let acc (s: {| prev: Result<_,string>; stop: bool |}) x =
    match s.prev, x with
    | Ok _, _ -> {| s with stop = true |} // Previous result was Ok => stop now
    | _, Ok _ -> {| s with prev = x |} // Don't stop, but remember the previous result
    | Error a, Error b -> {| s with prev = Error (a @ b) |}

sourceSequence
    |> Seq.scan acc st0 
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun s -> not s.stop)
    |> Seq.last
    |> (fun s -> s.prev)
```

---

P.S. also note that in F# list concatenation is `@`, not `++`. Are you coming from Haskell?

Comment: Thanks. That last part of your article was the "hack trick" I was having issue with this morning. Incidentally, it seems we can avoid extra iteration of the original sequence by using `Seq.interperse` to add empty elements (ie. `Error []`) to facilitate the `Seq.takeWhile` test and truncation after each real element. Ultimately, it does seem `Seq.skipToDefault` and `Seq.takeToDefault` would useful simplifiers. Thanks again.